# Why does this code yield error: <identifier> expected?

Tags: java

the code is below, I am only beginner to Java and have spend a good part of last 2h to try to access the newly created HelloWorld obj.

```
public class HelloWorld {

        int i; // Class Variable(State)

        void method() {
            System.out.println("Inside Method");
        }// Method (Behavior)
    }


    private HelloWorld obj = new HelloWorld();

    int jj = 8;

    obj.method();   // tried many variations of this part but to no success
```

I don't know what I tried to do but this seems to be the correct syntax

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
        System.out.println("Hello JBT!");

        TestClass obj = new TestClass();

        obj.method();

    }
```

Comment: Probably because it isn't in a method, and it isn't in a class. Notice that you end the class `HelloWorld` after `method`.... where is the code that follows supposed to be?

Comment: try creating a `public static void main` [method](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29276917/what-does-public-static-void-main-args-mean) inside your class and create your `HelloWorld` object there and call your `method()` there as well.

Comment: Yup. That syntax looks correct. You do not even need a `TestClass` you can put the `main` method with your `HelloWorld` class. give it a try.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try creating a `public static void main` method in your `HelloWorld` class. You can define your `HelloWorld` objects there and call any methods the `HelloWorld` class has.

```
class HelloWorld{
    int i;
    void method(){
        System.out.println("Inside Method");
    }
    public static void main(String... args){
        HelloWorld obj = new HelloWorld();
        obj.method();
    }
}
```

Output:

```
Inside Method
```