# No main methods found

Tags: java

```
package CS1301;

public class Homework4 {

    public static void Questions(int value) {
        if (value > 0) {
            int count = 1;

            while (count <= value) {
                if (value % count == 0) {
                    System.out.println(count);
                }  

                count = count ++;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

So I have been trying to get this to work for a bit now and I cant seem to find what is I'm doing wrong. When I try to run it it says "no main methods found, but I though the method defined by `public static void`. Also the purpose of this was to find the factors of the value. This is my first program so any pointers on better formatting would also be appreciated.

Comment: I don't see a `main` method in there.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You must have a `public static void` method called `main`, which accepts an array of arguments;

```
package CS1301;

public class Homework4 {

    public static void Questions(int value) {
        if (value > 0) {
            int count = 1;

            while (count <= value) {
                if (value % count == 0) {
                    System.out.println(count);
                }  

                count = count ++;
            }
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Questions(5);
    }
}
```

Comment: You're using the incorrect parameter for the `main` method.

Comment: Alright I got it to work, but I wanted to ask what exactly 'public static void' meant in the context I used it in originally. Do I actually need it? Also, how do I use the ++ operator correctly?

Comment: The duplicate question explain what each of those words meant.  The ++ operator is a separate question (which has probably already been answered about 25 times on this site).

Comment: @user8662311 Check out [public static void main meaning](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29276917/what-does-public-static-void-main-args-mean?noredirect=1&lq=1) and [++ meaning](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2371118/how-do-the-post-increment-i-and-pre-increment-i-operators-work-in-java)

Answer (score 2):

In java, to be able to launch something, you need a particular type of function, which can be recognize at the *start point* of the code

- it have to be a `void` method
- its name is `main`
- its parameter have to be an `array` of `String` (used in `command-line`)

Like this :

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    // some code like computation
    // or function calls 
}
```

[`Further details at Oracle Doc`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/getStarted/application/index.html#MAIN)

---

So you have two option, put your code inside this method, or inside an another one  :

```
public static void questions(int value){
    // ... your code
}

public static void main(String[] args){
    questions(2);
    questions(19);
}
```

OR

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    int value = 5;                     // <-- and put you value here
    if (value > 0) {
        int count = 1;
        while (count <= value) {
           //...
        }
    }
}
```

- first way is preferable your clarity
- better respect conventions and start naming variables and methods name with lover case `Questions` -> `questions`

Comment: I didn't downvote you, but you should follow conventions yourself ;)

Comment: @JacobG.like for what ?

Comment: Sometimes you have spaces between the ends of your methods, and sometimes you don't.  Your main method also doesn't compile, as `question` is not a method.