# multiple classes in Dr. Java

Tags: java, compiler-errors, drjava

The JDK compiler says it compiles, but when it runs I get this error:

> Static Error: This class does not have a static void main method accepting String[].

I am used to putting my methods class in one file and putting the main class in a sperate file.

How do I go about solving this issue?

```
    import java.util.Scanner;

public class Test{
  private final int classSize = 35;
  private int numEnrolled, numNeeded; 

  public void Input(){
   Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
   System.out.println("Enter the amount enrolled in your class");
   numEnrolled = in.nextInt();
   System.out.println("Your input is " + numEnrolled);       

   // Other parts of code that needs to be coded 
  }
}

class testRunner{
  static void main(String args[]){
    Test newTest = new Test();
    newTest.Input();

 }}
```

Comment: You might want to add `public`

Comment: Compilation-wise this is valid.  You can have a static method which returns nothing called `main` which accepts a `String[]` as a parameter, but that doesn't make it *the* `public static void main(String[] args)`.

Comment: I would read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29276917/what-does-public-static-void-main-args-mean) question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- In one file you can have only one public class, and multiple
  non-public classes
- Your filename has to match with the only public
  class
- To make your class runnable it should contain a ***public static
  void main(String args[])*** method, preferably in the public class

Your TestRunner.java should look like this

```
class Test{
    private final int classSize = 35;
    private int numEnrolled, numNeeded;

    public void Input(){
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter the amount enrolled in your class");
        numEnrolled = in.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Your input is " + numEnrolled);

        // Other parts of code that needs to be coded
    }
}

public class TestRunner{
    public static void main(String args[]){
        Test newTest = new Test();
        newTest.Input();

    }}
```

Edit:
If you want to leave the file name Test.java, this works too:

```
public class Test {
    private final int classSize = 35;
    private int numEnrolled, numNeeded;

    public void Input() {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter the amount enrolled in your class");
        numEnrolled = in.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Your input is " + numEnrolled);

        // Other parts of code that needs to be coded
    }
}

class TestRunner {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Test newTest = new Test();
        newTest.Input();

    }
}
```

Comment: So, I still need a second file for the testRunner class to use it in Test.java? I thought java can handle multiple classes in one file.

Comment: i added some explanation, java can handle multiple classes, but only one can be public

Comment: I tried using your second code string with Test.Java, and it is still giving me Static Error: This class does not have a static void main method accepting String[].

Comment: how are you trying to execute?

Comment: currently, its just trying to compile it (so far no errors) and run, but when I hit the run button that is the first thing that pops up. no prompt for input. i don't know if this is a Dr. Java issue or not

Comment: i dont know whats wrong, it should work. But then stick with the first code. The second is weird anyway, just posted because i found it interesting

Answer (score 0):

Change:

```
class testRunner{
  static void main(String args[]){
    Test newTest = new Test();
    newTest.Input();

 }}
```

to:

```
public class testRunner {
  public static void main(String args[]) {
    Test newTest = new Test();
    newTest.Input();
}}
```

`main()` must always be declared **public**